# What is the right syntax in PHP to check if a key from a variable exists in an object?

Tags: php

This is how I check if a key from a variable exists in an array:

```
$array=array();
$key='foo';
echo isset($array[$key])?$array[$key]:'';
```

**How do I check if a key from a variable exists in an object?**

```
$object = new stdClass();
$key='foo';
// echo isset($object->[$key])?$object->[$key]:'';
```

Update 1. I also want to do the equivalent of `echo $array[$key]` to the object.

Update 2. For you crazy people out there here's the syntax I was looking for:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$key='foo';
echo isset($object->{$key})?$object->{$key}:'';
```

Comment: Do you mean to check if a property exists in an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/property_exists) to do that:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->foo = "bar";
$key='foo';
if (property_exists($object, $key)) {
    echo $object->$key;
}
```

Comment: How do I echo $array[$key] the object version?

Comment: Actually it was $key['foo'] and I had to use $object->{$key['foo']}.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check if the property exists

```
if(isset($obj->property)){
```